# Is it possible to make headless and flexible tabs in JS?

Tags: reactjs

[I want to make tabs like this for my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LEeE.png)

But I'm not sure if i can get a look like this while using js.This is my first react project and I want to make flexible tabs like this in the image. I write this code below in App.js file:

```
import { TabPanel, useTabs } from "react-headless-tabs";
import { TabSelector } from "./TabSelector";
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Routes,
Route,
Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import UserList from './components/UserList'
import UserDetail from './components/UserDetail'
import Login from './components/Login';
function App() {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useTabs([
    "account",
    "company",
    "team",
    "billing",
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
      <nav className="flex border-b border-gray-300">
        <TabSelector
          isActive={selectedTab === "list"}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab("list")}
        >
          My Account
        </TabSelector>
        <TabSelector
          isActive={selectedTab === "detail"}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab("detail")}
        >
          Company
        </TabSelector>
        <TabSelector
          isActive={selectedTab === "login"}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab("login")}
        >
          Team Members
        </TabSelector>
      </nav>
      <div className="p-4">
        <TabPanel hidden={selectedTab !== "list"}>List</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel hidden={selectedTab !== "detail"}>Detail</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel hidden={selectedTab !== "login"}>Login</TabPanel>
      </div>
    </>
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="list">List</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="detail">Detail</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="login">Login</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='list' element={<UserList/>}>           
          </Route>
          <Route path='detail' element={<UserDetail/>}>    
          </Route>
          <Route path='login' element={<Login/>}>    
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting `Can't resolve './TabSelector'` error. I installed react-headless-tabs and @material-ui/lab. My package.json file is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@mui/material": "^5.12.3",
    "react-headless-tabs": "^6.0.4"
  }
}
```

Can I make tabs like that while using react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use install the headlessui library

```
npm install @headlessui/react
```

For tabs, you can write:

```
import { Tab } from '@headlessui/react'

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Group>
      <Tab.List>
        <Tab>Tab 1</Tab>
        <Tab>Tab 2</Tab>
        <Tab>Tab 3</Tab>
      </Tab.List>
      <Tab.Panels>
        <Tab.Panel>Content 1</Tab.Panel>
        <Tab.Panel>Content 2</Tab.Panel>
        <Tab.Panel>Content 3</Tab.Panel>
      </Tab.Panels>
    </Tab.Group>
  )
}
```

For more info, you can visit:-

https://headlessui.com/react/tabs

Hope it will be helpful.